# Optaplanner : Can "terminate early" return the best solution instead of the last solution calculated?

Tags: optaplanner

For my project, i would like "solver.terminateEarly()" method to return the best solution instead of the last solution calculated. Any way to do this ?

The following is the solver class :

```
public class ProblemSolver implements SolverEventListener {

private static ProblemSolver instance = new ProblemSolver();
private volatile Solver solver; 
private ScoreDirector  guiScoreDirector;
private Problem unsolvedProblem;
public static final String SOLVER_CONFIG = "/com/abcdl/be/solver/ABCDLSolverConfig.xml";
private ProblemSolver(){
}

public static ProblemSolver getInstance(){
    return instance;
}

public void initializeSolver()
{
    System.out.println("------------------Start SOLVE--------------------");
    createSolver();
    System.out.println("------------------Solver Created-------------------");
    createScoreDirector(solver);
    System.out.println("------------------Create Planning Problem-------------------");
    createPlannningProblem();
    System.out.println("------------------Planning Problem created-------------------");
}

/**
 *   // Build the Solver
 * @return
 */
public void createSolver()
{
    try{
         SolverFactory solverFactory = new XmlSolverFactory(SOLVER_CONFIG);
            solver = solverFactory.buildSolver();
            solver.addEventListener(this);
        }
    catch (Exception e) {
         e.printStackTrace();

    }
}


public void createScoreDirector(Solver solver)
{
     ScoreDirectorFactory scoreDirectorFactory = solver.getScoreDirectorFactory();
     guiScoreDirector = scoreDirectorFactory.buildScoreDirector();
}


public void createPlannningProblem()
{
    unsolvedProblem = new Problem();

    Collection<Node> nodeList =  new ArrayList<Node>(Graph.getInstance().getNodes());
    nodeList.remove(Graph.getInstance().getNt()); // the root is removed from the list
    unsolvedProblem.setNodeList(nodeList);

    guiScoreDirector.setWorkingSolution(unsolvedProblem);
}

/**
 * Notifies the solver that it should stop at its earliest convenience.
 * @return true if successful
 */
public boolean terminateEarly()
{
    if (solver == null)
        return false;

    return solver.terminateEarly();
}

public void bestSolutionChanged(BestSolutionChangedEvent event) {
     if (solver.isEveryProblemFactChangeProcessed()) {
         // final is needed for thread visibility
         final Solution latestBestSolution = event.getNewBestSolution();
         // Migrate it to the event thread
         SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
             public void run() {
                 guiScoreDirector.setWorkingSolution(latestBestSolution);
                 Tab2.getInstance().getProgressPB().setString(""+latestBestSolution.getScore());
             }
         });
     }
 }

public Solver getSolver() {
    return solver;
}

public ScoreDirector getGuiScoreDirector() {
    return guiScoreDirector;
}
```

}

The solver task :

```
public static class SolveTask extends SwingWorker<Solution, Void> {

    private Solution bestSolution = null;

    protected Solution doInBackground() throws Exception {
        final Solution planningProblem = ProblemSolver.getInstance().getGuiScoreDirector().getWorkingSolution();
        System.out.println("------------------SET Planning Problem-------------------");
        ProblemSolver.getInstance().getSolver().setPlanningProblem(planningProblem);
        System.out.println("------------------Solving the problem-------------------");
        ProblemSolver.getInstance().getSolver().solve(); // solve the problem using the constraint satisfaction solver
        bestSolution = (Problem) ProblemSolver.getInstance().getSolver().getBestSolution();

        return bestSolution;
    }

    protected void done()
    {
        Solution newSolution =  null;
        try {
            newSolution = get();
        } catch (CancellationException e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "\nSolving process was cancelled\n", "",
                      JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
             JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "\nSolving process was terminated due to an unhandled exception\n", "ERROR",
                      JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }
        if (newSolution != null) {
            ProblemSolver.getInstance().getGuiScoreDirector().setWorkingSolution(newSolution);
            Tab2.getInstance().getProgressPB().setString(""+ProblemSolver.getInstance().getGuiScoreDirector().calculateScore());
            Tab2.getInstance().setScore(""+ProblemSolver.getInstance().getGuiScoreDirector().calculateScore());
         }

         System.out.println("------------------END SOLVER--------------------");
    }
}
```

Comment: In 6.1 it's indeed a bit of a pain, because you get the `BestSolutionChangedEvent` in the solver thread - and worse, if you're using `addProblemFactChange()`'s, there might not even be a new best solution, or a new initialized best solution or a new initialized feasible best solution yet, when you call `terminateEarly()`. I suspect you don't want to terminateEarly just yet in that case, but want to wait for a feasible solution (unless you're quiting your app).

Comment: Let's gather requirements in [this jira issue](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/PLANNER-251)

Comment: @GeoffreyDeSmet, exactly. Is there maybe any workaround i could try until a solution is found for this issue ?

Comment: workound is to register a best solution listener (which will be called on the solver thread) and have it store the latest best solution in an AtomicObject, so you can fetch it on the main thread after calling terminateEarly().

Comment: @GeoffreyDeSmet I'm not sure i got it. Do you suggest to implement the SolverEventListener on the SolveTask class ?